# Update xml file attributes with MySQL query result

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an XML file that I need to update its attributes with results from a MySQL query:

```
<dataValue>
  <value var="one" val="1"/>
  <value var="two" val="2"/>
  <value var="three" val="3"/>
</dataValue>
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(person_id) from person
```

which would output say 15. How can I update the above XML, and replace `var="1" to var="15"`

i.e with the MySQL query result via PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Load your xml with XmlReader / XmlWriter, DomDocument or simplexml or some other xml parsing / reading package of your choice. Find the "value" tag in the xml you need and change the attribute in question.